# How to link button event.click with xamarin.driod from xamarin.form

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Am new to xamarin.form having a blockage...
This is what I want to do.
I have a button in welcome.xaml in xamarin.form and I want to perform a click event but I want a method from xamarin.driod to be implemented in the click.event.

Those this makes sense to anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically prefer using IOC and Interfaces to implement platform specific logic in the Core project, but simple way to do it may just be to set a static Action on your pages code behind.

```
public partial class WelcomePage
{
    public static Action DroidAction { get; set; }

    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DroidAction == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Action was not set");
        }
        DroidAction?.Invoke();
    }
```

Your Droids OnCreate could be an option of where to do this.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        WelcomePage.DroidAction = new Action(() => Debug.WriteLine("I a platform specific action!"));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom control.

So you could handle the click event in the `Android` or `IOS`.

Read [here](https://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-controls-in-xamarin-forms-on-android/) about how to create a custom controls in `xamarin.forms`

You could also assign a static class that exist in the shared project from your driod project.